# Turning right from a two-way road onto another two-way road

Tags: traffic, driving

Alberta's driver's [guide](https://www.alberta.ca/turning.aspx) says "when turning right from a two-way road onto another two-way road, stay centred in your turning lane, and no more than 1 metre (3 feet) from the curb or edge of the road." However, it then says "If it is safe, complete your turn by turning into the first available traffic lane on the right when there is space to allow you to gently accelerate and change lanes. After you complete the turn, look well ahead along your intended path." Does that mean you don't actually have to stay centred in your original turning lane - you can just turn into the first available traffic lane? Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. A diagram might help. Or at least more information on how many lanes there are in each road, whether there are multiple lanes signed for a right turn, etc. Obviously you don't stay centred in your original lane because you turn into another road - you only stay centred until you start to turn - but I guess that's not what you're asking.

Comment: (I have no idea if this is off topic - it's evidently not about a legal requirement, but the official driver's guide may have some standing in cases involving driving offences or negligence.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments! There is no diagram for the part where the guide says   "when turning right from a two-way road onto another two-way road, stay centred in your turning lane, and no more than 1 metre (3 feet) from the curb or edge of the road." For the part where the guide says "If it is safe, complete your turn by turning into the first available traffic lane on the right when there is space to allow you to gently accelerate and change lanes. After you complete the turn, look well ahead along your intended path", it seems the implied diagram is found right above the said part.

Comment: Yes, It's not easy to follow the guide when there is not enough information.

So my question is if I can just pick and choose any availability lane I want once I have made a right turn? Is it legal to do that? Or should I turn right into the lane (I think it's called the curb lane) that is closest to the curb side? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure what they mean is "Don't swing wide." That is, cross the lane markings or where the lane marking would be if you went straight across the intersection.

Watch vehicles when they turn--a lot of people swing wide (to the left) when turning right.

From [Connecticut's Driver's Manual (PDF)](https://portal.ct.gov/dmv/-/media/DMV/DMV-PDFs/r12eng122019.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> Where there are no signs or lane markings to control turning, you
> should turn from the lane that is closest to the direction you want to
> go and turn into the lane closest to the one you came from. This way,
> you will cross the fewest lanes of traffic. **When making turns, go from
> one lane to the other as directly as possible without crossing lane
> lines or interfering with traffic.** Once you have completed your turn
> and once it is safe to do so, you can change to another lane if you
> need to. Remember to always look and signal before changing lanes.
>
> • Right turns. On right turns, **avoid swinging wide to the left before
> making the turn**. If you swing wide, the driver behind you may think
> you are changing lanes or going to turn left and may try to pass you
> on the right. If you swing wide as you complete the turn, drivers who
> are in the far lane will not expect to see you there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!